# netTCPBinding configuration cannot transport small sized data - socket connetion was aborted

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF service hosted by a Windows Service.  It has a Publish/Subscribe relationship to zero to many clients within the network.  The binding is net.TCP.  The WCF Service provides a "Subscribe" method to the client so the client can register a callback handler.  The WCF Service periodically calls methods in the callback handler of any currently subscribed clients.

The interface is defined (with abreviation) below:

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    void ReturnInitialData(
        InitialData initialData,
        CraneState recentState,
        VerticalCraneState recentVerticalCraneState,
        ThresholdState recentThresholdState,
        StationaryStatusFlagsState recentStationaryStatusFlagState,
        LightsState recentLights,
        BarrierRiskState recentBarrierRiskState
        );
```

When the service calls ReturnInitialData() with approximately 42000 bytes of data, it works fine.  When the service calls it with approximately 70000 bytes of data it throws the following exception:

```
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an
error processing your message or a receive timeout being
exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying
network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:10:00'.
```

This is the netTcpBinding configuration:

```
General
CloseTimeout                00:00:20
HostNameComparisonMode      StrongWildcard
ListenBacklog               0
MaxBufferPoolSize           524288
MaxBufferSize               2147483647
MaxConnections              0
MaxReceivedMessageSize      2147483647
OpenTimeout                 00:01:00
PortSharingEnabled          False
ReceiveTimeout              00:10:00
SendTimeout                 00:10:00
TransactionFlow             False
TransactionProtocol         Ole Transactions
TransferMode                Buffered


ReaderQuotas Properties
MaxArrayLength              0
MaxBytesPerRead             0
MaxDepth                    0
MaxNameTableCharCount       0
MaxStringContentLength      0


ReliableSession Properties
Enabled                     False
InactivityTimeout           00:10:00
Ordered                     True
```

Any leads or pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to enable WCF Tracing and Message Logging, which will allow you to monitor/review communication to/from the WCF service and hopefully isolate the issue (which, based on the provided error message, may likely be a timeout issue.)

The following links provide a good overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Regards,

Comment: +1, This is the first thing you should do whenever you get weird errors from WCF.

Comment: Thanks adkSerenity and shambulator, please see the following answer for my results.  I'm marking this answer and "the answer" because you lead me onto the correct path.

Answer (score 4):

adkSerenity and shambulator,

Thank you.  I found the problem.  It turned out to be a buffer size.  I was pretty sure it wasn't a timeout because the shortest timeout was set to one minute and I could reproduce the error in thirty seconds.

I had been avoiding WCF Tracing and Message Logging because it was so intimidating. So much to read, so little time.  ;-}

When I generated the output at looked at it with the viewer, it might as well have been Martian. After studying it for a while in a fog, I finally get the impression that the loss of communication was not the fault of the service. Then the light bulb went on and I checked the client's config file. Sure enough, the MaxBufferSize was set to 65535, effectively cutting off the 70000 byte message.

Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.